# How to hide NULL rows in telerik?

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

[image]

How can I hide these yellow filled rows in telerik table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An appropriate approach to accomplish this specific part is to apply filtering like this

```
=Fields.AllowanceType <> NULL
=Fields.AllowanceAmount <> 0
```

As the amount isn't string that's why we can't compare string with integer.

Answer (score 1):

Doonie

i think this my help you.
[Telerik responde about your questions](https://www.telerik.com/forums/hide-telerik-table-row), basically say you only need to do filtering condition like this `= Len(IsNull(Fields.MyField, "")) > 0`

Comment: I already have been to this thread before but When I apply this filter on my expression which in my case is 'Allowance Type', it gives me 'True' and 'False' in return so if the column is null it shows 'False' and if the column contains any value it shows 'True', I'm not even passing anything that show this kind of information so I'm still numb.

Comment: Plus I want to apply filtering on the fields instead of whole table as I got 2 different columns whose values I'm getting from 2 different tables. Is there any chance to do that ?

Comment: cant you provide example?